# Add images as buttons into specific locations (Actionscript 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have been looking into loading images from an external folder as buttons to specific locations in AS3. I've tried working with arrays but to be honest I am just at a loss considering I am fairly new to more advanced programming in AS3.

Basically what I want to accomplish is loading 4 images to the scene randomly on 4 different specific locations in the scene as buttons.

let's say for example these locations.

x.100, y.200 - x.300, y.200

x.100, y.400 - x.300, y.400

Does anybody know a convenient way of doing so? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Per request; this is the code I currently have and only creates an array at the top left corner without randomization of the imported images:

```
    var imagesArray2:Array = new Array('img/img0.jpg', 'img/img1.jpg','img/img2.jpg','img/img3.jpg');
    var loadedArray2:Array = new Array();

    function loadImagen2():void{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < imagesArray2.length; i++){
    var loader2:Loader = new Loader();
    loader2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded2);
    loader2.load(new URLRequest(imagesArray2[i]));
    }
    }

    function loaded2(e:Event):void{

    loadedArray2.push(e.target.content);

    if(loadedArray2.length == imagesArray2.length){    

    for(var i:int = 0; i < loadedArray2.length; i++){
       loadedArray2[i].x = 0 + i * 100;
       addChild(loadedArray2[i]);
   }    
   }
   }


   loadImagen2();

   stop();
```

Comment: Show code of what you have so far (loading & positioning) then someone can help you edit it to load at specific X/Y locations.

Comment: I was able to create an array that loads an instance of a movieclip with multiple frames and all the different images in there. Then splice off the ones it used and putting them in two rows. So it's all good now!

Answer (score 2):

This example is little help for your query here i have been used object then i try to allocate the position of object in random position..

```
package 
{
     import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class addchild 
{

    var movie:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    var boxMc:box;

    public function addchild(Mc:MovieClip) 
    {
        for (var a = 1; a <= 3; a++ )
    {
        movie = Mc;
        boxMc = new box();
        Mc.addChild(boxMc);
        Mc.addChild(boxMc).x = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 200);
        Mc.addChild(boxMc).y = Math.round(Math.random() * 200);
    }       


    }

}
```